# Flutter backup user data

Tags: android, database, firebase, flutter

So i've recently discovered Flutter as a great way to develop apps for IOS/Android at the same time and i've come up with a project i'd like to realize. It's nothing new, i just want to build an app that helps you keep track of all the money you have / don't have (in my case). I know that this is not something new and there are some really good apps for this but i want some special features none of these apps has (+ it's a project not that difficult and i can get a ton of coding experience).

I am looking for the best / a very good way to store user data. Each user should be able to store all past transactions and how much money they still have left. From what i've read SharedPreferences aren't the way to go as they aren't good at "storing a lot of data" so it's reccomended to go with an actual database. 
As i am someone that very frequently resets his phone (rooting and stuff is really fun) i'd love to have the option to backup the database in the cloud as well. If my research is correct i can do this two ways:
I can either have a local database stored on the device and create an option in the app to export the db to e.g Google Drive / Dropbox and import the db from there or i could go with a firebase from google. I'd prefer the second option as then i could implement it in a way that the user doesn't ever need to press "backup data" but the data will always get synced with the firebase and be available offline.
I've found tons of ways and tutorials on how to do this on android, yet i could not find anything for flutter. And i don't really know how to secure a firebase (and i don't really want to know either, i'm not that much into databases).

What are your suggestions? Should i

Go with a local database or 

Try setting up a firebase


 Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase seems like a great option. Note you only have 1GB of free real time database storage.

In terms of integrating Firebase with Flutter you should start reading [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules)

Comment: If i didn't missunderstand this this tutorial is for when you want all users to be able to view the same data. I want a way that each user get's his "own part of the database" and can't see the data of other users.

Comment: @JulianSchubert so each user will have an account and will only be able to access his data by logging in ?

Comment: This would be the ideal solution yes.

Comment: @JulianSchubert if that's the case maybe you could do it with Firebase's Real Time Database security rules. https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules but I would suggest an Application server

Comment: This seems to be the solution for my problem. Thank you very much!
"Content-owner only: Restrict access to content by user." is exactly what i need

Comment: @JulianSchubert if my answer solved your question make sure to check the V next to my answer. Good luck.

Comment: Firebase works for me and allows you to store user specific data (for authorized users) after applying some security rules in the console used to admin your collections/documents.

Answer (score -1):

SharedPreferences are mostly used for storing only important information like userId tokens, session timeouts etc etc.
In my opinion go with firebase, so that you can keep record of probably every single transaction. 
You can even go with local storage but as the data grows it would be good to keep it syncronized across cloud.

Comment: The most important thing for me is that each user will have an account and will only be able to access his data by logging in. I could not find any tutorials on how to achieve this